# How to use zero quantity case in Android quantity strings (plurals)?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to use the `getQuantityString` method in `Resources` to retrieve `Quantity Strings` based on android developer guidelines `Quantity String` in my Kotlin application.
`One` and the `other` case is ok, but `zero` is not working.
This is my code.

```
// text
txtNewProfileCount.text = resources.getQuantityString(
            R.plurals.shortlists_profile_count,
            filteredCandidateVMList.size,
            filteredCandidateVMList.size
        )

// plurals code
<plurals name="shortlists_profile_count">
    <item quantity="zero">Sorry, there are no new profiles in your various shortlists</item>
    <item quantity="one">Please review the new profile in your various shortlists</item>
    <item quantity="other">Please review the %1$d new profiles in your various shortlists</item>
</plurals>
```

In case the quantity is `one` and `other`, the result is correct.
But in the `zero` cases, the result is **`Please review the 0 new profiles in your various shortlists`**.
This isn't the result I want.
How to solve when the quantity is `zero`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `zero` case is never used in English. English uses only `one` and `other`. Plural resources are intended only for grammatically unique constructs of specific languages. This is explained in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#Plurals):

> The selection of which string to use is made solely based on
> grammatical *necessity*. In English, a string for zero is ignored even
> if the quantity is 0, because 0 isn't grammatically different from 2,
> or any other number except 1 ("zero books", "one book", "two books",
> and so on).

So you have to manually select a separate String resource using an `if` statement in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Android Plurals is not support zero case now.
So you need to make your own function for this.

Here is one example.

```
fun getQuantityString(resources:Resources, resId:Int, quantity:Int, zeroResId:Int):String {
  if (quantity == 0) {
    return resources.getString(zeroResId)
  } else {
    return resources.getQuantityString(resId, quantity, quantity)
  }
}
```